# Virtual member call in constructor - why is one okay and the other not?

Tags: c#

With the code below, Resharper raises a 'virtual member call in constructor' warning:

```
public class UserDetailViewModel : Screen
{
    public UserDetailViewModel()
    {
        // DisplayName is a virtual member of Screen
        DisplayName = "User Details"; 
    }
}
```

Whereas if I change the code so it's like this, the warning disappears:

```
public class UserDetailViewModel : Screen
{
    public UserDetailViewModel()
    {
        SetName();
    }

    private void SetName()
    {
        DisplayName = "User Details"; 
    }
}
```

Why does one raise a warning and the other not?  Is the second way somehow correct, or is it just beyond the limit of what ReSharper can detect as potentially dangerous?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just a limitation of ReSharper. It applies a bunch of heuristics to find code that it can warn about, but it won't find everything. Doing so would require solving the halting problem. It's not doable.

The lesson here is quite simple:
*the absence of a warning does not mean that there is nothing to warn about.*

Comment: Thanks jalf.  To avoid the issue, is it acceptable to change `SetName()` to be public and call it after instantiation, eg: `userDetailViewModel.SetName();` ? Or is there a better solution? (this should really be a new question, I know)!

Comment: It is possible to find that the constructor can potentially call a virtual member without doing halting analysis.

Comment: @Town `new UserDetailViewModel().SetName()` is not a good choice because it makes it the caller's responsibility to call `SetName()`. I would choose to ignore the warning instead.

Comment: @Hemal Pandya: it feels wrong to me too, although ignoring a warning like that seems wrong-er!

Comment: Why does `DisplayName` have to be virtual? That's what seems weird to me. If it is part of the object's initialization, then there's little reason for it to be virtual.

Comment: I have a more extensive Java background... putting a `@SuppressWarning(<whatver>)` is not uncommon.

Comment: @jalf: I assume you mean DisplayName rather than SetName.  It's part of Caliburn.Micro, so I can't answer that I'm afraid!

Answer (score 3):

In Caliburn.Micro, it's common to set the DisplayName by overriding the OnInitialize() method, e.g.

```
    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        DisplayName = "User Details";
        base.OnInitialize();
    }
```

OnInitialize() is only called once, and you do not raise a warning in Resharper anymore. See also [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/10/08/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-6a-screens-conductors-and-composition.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The warning is given because of the problem that can arise in the following situation

- An object of a derived type of `UserDetailViewModel`, say "ConcreteModel` is being constructed
- `ConcreteModel` overrides  `Screen.DisplayName` property. In the property's set method it depends on the `ConcreteModel` constructed having completed, say it accesses another member that is initialized in the constructor.

In this case, the above code will throw an exception.

The right way to solve this is by declaring `DisplayName` to be `sealed` in `UserDetailViewModel`. Now you can feel confident that it is ok to ignore the warning.

The following example demonstrates it. Uncommenting the lines in `Der` causes compilation error.

```
class Base
{
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

class Der : Base
{
    public Der()
    {
        //  ok to ignore virtual member access here
        DisplayName = "Der";
    }
    public override sealed string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

class Leaf : Der
{ 
    private string _displayName;
    public Leaf()
    {
        _displayName = "default";
    }
    //override public string DisplayName
    //{
    //    get { return _displayName; }
    //    set { if (!_displayName.Equals(value)) _displayName = value; }
    //}
}
```